# A bootable rootkit scanner for Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, rootkit

I was just wondering, is there any good app for Ubuntu that you could burn on a DVD from an *.iso file, choose it from the boot menu before Ubuntu even starts and then scan the system externally for the kind of threats that are good at hiding from antiviruses, i.e. rootkits? I know there's probably no need for something like that but I'd like to make sure just in case, and I heard Kaspersky makes something like this for Windows so there's probably an Ubuntu counterpart somewhere too. It would be nice if it was user friendly and easy to beginners, but I could always try to learn it if there's need to.

Comment: Your question is fairly broad, you can use almost any live CD to perform security scans (you would install once you boot or make a usb with persistence).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as a matter of fact, there is. It's called the [**Ubuntu Live Environment**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD), and it comes with every Ubuntu ISO. Simply grab your installation drive and boot from that.

The live environment is a full-fledged Linux operating system that lives completely in memory. You can install packages (like the famous `rkhunter`), recover your system, and do pretty much anything you'd normally be able to do from a desktop install of Ubuntu.

The live image is (normally) read-only, so your changes won't persist. However, this also means any malware loaded into it would be gone following a reboot.

While there are specialized tools for this as well, the live environment is probably one of the easiest to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Antivirus LiveCDs. The most popular Linux-based are:

- [Dr.Web LiveDisk](http://download.geo.drweb.com/pub/drweb/livedisk/drweb-livedisk-900-cd.iso)
- [Kaspersky Resciue Disk](http://rescuedisk.kaspersky-labs.com/rescuedisk/updatable/kav_rescue_10.iso)
- [Avira Rescue System](http://professional.avira-update.com/package/rs_avira/unix/int/rescue-system.iso)

Some of them are based on Ubuntu or Gentoo. My favorite is Dr.Web.